# Show empty field if content is "00.00.0000"

Tags: php, mysql

How can I pass "datetime" to the database with "NULL". So that "0000-00-00 00:00:00" is not displayed as value.

The sql column is not nullable. The value must be "1000-01-01 00:00:00" so that nothing is displayed in the frontend.

How can I do this via PHP

```
'ERSCHEINUNGSDATUM'     => array(
create_field_info(TABLE_VD_ART, 'erscheinungsdatum', 'vd_date_to_xtc_date')
),
```

Comment: What keeps you from using `NULL`?

Comment: If a date is assigned, it should also be transferred, otherwise just "null". Otherwise the value 0000-00-00 is stored automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to tackle the "function" of "vd_date_to_xtc_date".

```
function vd_date_to_xtc_date($input_date, $input_format = 'd.m.Y', $output_format = 'Y-m-d', $add_seconds = 0) {
    if (!$input_date)
    {
        return "1000-01-01 00:00:00";
    }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the column in the table nullable? If it is, you can say:

```php
'ERSCHEINUNGSDATUM'     => null,
```

Otherwise you have to make the column nullable, you can also set a default value of `NULL` in the database

Comment: Does this mean that I have to tell the field in MySQL that it can be empty?

How do I make the query in general. If a date is assigned, it should also be transferred, otherwise just "null". Otherwise the value 0000-00-00 is stored automatically.

Comment: You're right. The column is not nullable. The value must be "1000-01-01 00:00:00" so that nothing is displayed in the frontend. How can I set the value if no date is entered?

Comment: It's better to make the field nullable and do a null check